# Drupal 8.4 Bartik theme on internet explorer 11

Tags: theming

I have finished my site on localhost and it displays fine, on all browsers.
 When launching to server it shows fine in firefox, chrome, etc.

In Internet Explorer 11 however there are render issues. it just shows it all down one side.( left hand side).

I have tried the compatability method as described for the 7xcore and Microsoft. IE: I have added the site to the compatability list. Cleared all the history and the drupal cache but it has made no difference.

Site still shows as if no CSS is being invoked.

Many thanks
Allen

Answer (score 0):

SORTED IT.
 in configuration.
UNCHECK:- Aggregate CSS files
UNCHECK:- Aggregate JavaScript files
Now displays correctly.